# Preserve hyperlink navigation in inline tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have an inline tinyMCE editor where the HTML text may contain hyperlinks. If the user clicks a hyperlink, I want them to go to the URL. If they click elsewhere, I want to enter edit mode.

The HTML:

```
<div id="tinymce">
  <p>User should be able to <a id="mylink" href="http://google.com">navigate to a link</a> and also edit the text by clicking outside the link.</p>
</div>
```

The script:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tinymce',
  inline: true
});

$('#mylink').on('click', function(e) {
  // This never fires
  console.log('Link clicked...');
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdog33/uLhdq447/

As you can see, I had an idea to hook into the click event of the hyperlink and manually send the user off with window.location.href, but the event doesn't fire. If I uncomment the tinymce initialization, it *does* fire, so obviously tinymce is interfering somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thariama's answer is nearly correct - thank you for getting me on the right track. Below is my final code:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tinymce',
  inline: true,
  setup: function(editor){
    editor.on('init', function() {
      $(editor.getBody()).on('click', 'a[href]', function(e) {
        window.location.href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
      });
   }
});
```

- Fixed syntax error where 'editor' was used twice as a parameter
- Changed the event handling to work on all hyperlinks, even when content is replaced by user
- Added navigation to hyperlink

Comment: thanks for letting other users know what you did - plus one

Comment: Keep in mind if you do it this way, ctrl-click/command-click will no longer open them in new tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way here is to use the tinymce parameter `setup` and add a click handler to the link element when the editor is ready (use the `init` event).

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tinymce',
  inline: true,
  setup: function(editor){
     editor.on('init', function(editor){
       $(editor.getBody()).find('#mylink').on('click', function(e) {
         // This never fires
         console.log('Link clicked...');
       });
     });
  }

});
```